# DB tables design with a lot of attributes

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures

I'd like to know how the db design should look like in this case.

[image]

What comes to my mind is a table for every entity like:

```
Engine  
EngineDesign  
ElectricalSystem  
Drivetrain  
etc.
```

But it looks to me as a lot of tables. Is my idea ok or is it excessive?

And what about the Drivetrain? Today we have 8 gears but it can change whenever a manufacturer comes with something different.

Should it be like this:
Table (columns)

```
DrivetrainId | 1st | 2nd | 3rd | etc.
```

Or

Table (rows)

```
DrivetrainId | Gears
1            | 1st
2            | 2nd
3            | 3rd
etc.
```

Comment: Did I overlook something, or are all four of those identical? If they're not actually identical, how do you identify an engine? (In fact, even if they *are* identical, how do you identify an engine? By the value of engine type?)

Comment: It was me who overlooked that all four vehicles differ only in Trims. :-) I'm interested in the relation ENGINE - Type, Bore, Stroke, etc.; DRIVETRAIN - 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. etc. and how to put this attributes into the tables. If its ok to "mirror" the web page design to the db or there is a better approach. The picture is just an example of the result, the values doesn't matter. Look at it as there was only 1 column (1 vehicle).

Comment: Let me ask you waht do you want to do with this information once you have it? Will you be reading it as a group or querying on indivudual items? Somethings can possibily be put into a notes field if you don't intend to query them but just display the information.

Comment: I think the queries would be very granular. In case of the product or a car it would be compared - on basis of displacement, speed, fuel consumption etc. or on the selection of the user. He/she wants ie a red car with this engine and that dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't judge the soundness of a database design by counting tables. There's no such thing as "too many tables" normal form, or "not enough tables" normal form.  There's also no such thing as "too many columns" normal form, or "not enough columns" normal form.

As it stands *today*, having one column for each of the transmission gear ratios might still get you to 5NF. That's because it's not having multiple columns whose values come from the same domain that's a problem. It's having multiple columns whose values come from the same domain *and have the same meaning* that's a problem.

Clearly, 8th gear and 1st gear have different meanings. In fact, you might consider them to be drawn from different domains. My guess is that 0.67 isn't a valid value for 1st gear, and that 4.85 isn't a valid value for 8th.

When these are stored in different columns,

- it's easy to enforce the constraint that every row have a value for each of the 8 transmission gear ratios, and
- constraints on the range of valid values for each gear ratio is really simple.  (But you have to accommodate NULLs for later designs having only 5 or 6 gears, and that raises normalization issues.)

When they're stored as rows,

- it's harder--perhaps impossible--to enforce the constraint that each vehicle have a value for each of the 8 transmission gear ratios, and
- constraints on the range of valid values for each gear ratio is more complicated. (Especially when you later accommodate designs that have only 5 or 6 gears.)

Answer (score -1):

My first instinct would be to do something with an Attributes table and a Cars table (I'm assuming cars?)

```
Attributes
AttributeId | AttributeCategory | AttributeDesc

Cars    
CarId | AttributeId | AttributeValue
```

Edit: See comments below @HLGEM's explanation why an Entity-Attribute-Value table is not a good idea in this example.

Comment: Yes, the picture is about cars, but I've seen that price comparison sites are using something similar because they have to compare a lot of product attributes.

Comment: Worst possible solution for querying later.

Comment: @HLGEM Can you explain why, or point me at an article so I can learn better?  I've found similar solutions to be more flexible later (when attributes are added or deleted).

Comment: EAV tables are very poor performers and should only be used as a last resort. They are extemely hard to query especially if you don't know how many attributes you have and become a contention point as everyone is always accessing. To find all ten attributes for instance you have to join tothe same table ten times. If you have 20 attributes then 20 times. He knows what fields he wants so he should not use EAV. If you truly need EAV information as you have no way of knowing what attributes you have, then you should use a nosql databse not a relational database.